# Pandas N-Grams to Columns

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d=['Hello', 'Helloworld']
f=pd.DataFrame({'strings':d})
f
    strings
0   Hello
1   Helloworld
```

I'd like to split each string into chunks of 3 characters and use those as headers to create a matrix of 1s or 0s, depending on if a given row has the chunk of 3 characters.

Like this:

```
    Strings     Hel     low     orl
0   Hello         1       0       0
1   Helloworld    1       1       1
```

Notice that the string "Hello" has a 0 for the "low" column as it is only assigning a 1 for exact partial matches. If there is more than 1 match (i.e. if the string were "HelHel", it would still only assign a 1 (though it would also be nice to know how to count it and thus assign a 2 instead).

Ultimately, I'm trying to prepare my data for us in an LSHForest via SKLearn.
Therefore, I anticipate many different string values.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
#Split into chunks of exactly 3
def split(s, chunk_size):
    a = zip(*[s[i::chunk_size] for i in range(chunk_size)])
    return [''.join(t) for t in a]
cols=[split(s,3) for s in f['strings']]
cols

[['Hel'], ['Hel', 'low', 'orl']]

#Get all elements into one list:
import itertools
colsunq=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(cols))
#Remove duplicates:
colsunq=list(set(colsunq))
colsunq

['orl', 'Hel', 'low']
```

So now, all I need to do is create a column in **f** for each element in **colsunq** and add 1 if the string in the 'strings' column has a match with the chunk for each given column header.

Thanks in advance!

**Note:**
In case shingling is preferred:

```
#Shingle into strings of exactly 3
def shingle(word):
    a = [word[i:i + 3] for i in range(len(word) - 3 + 1)]
    return [''.join(t) for t in a]
#Shingle (i.e. "hello" -> "hel","ell",'llo')
a=[shingle(w) for w in f['strings']]
#Get all elements into one list:
import itertools
colsunq=list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(a))
#Remove duplicates:
colsunq=list(set(colsunq))
colsunq
['wor', 'Hel', 'ell', 'owo', 'llo', 'rld', 'orl', 'low']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def str_chunk(s, k):
    i, j = 0, k
    while j <= len(s):
        yield s[i:j]
        i, j = j, j + k

def chunkit(s, k):
    return [_ for _ in str_chunk(s, k)]

def count_chunks(s, k):
    return pd.value_counts(chunkit(s, k))
```

---

***demonstration***

```
f.strings.apply(chunkit, k=3)

0              [Hel]
1    [Hel, low, orl]
Name: strings, dtype: object

f.strings.apply(count_chunks, k=3).fillna(0)
```

[image]

---

***shingling***

```
def str_shingle(s, k):
    i, j = 0, k
    while j <= len(s):
        yield s[i:j]
        i, j = i + 1, j + 1

def shingleit(s, k):
    return [_ for _ in str_shingle(s, k)]

def count_shingles(s, k):
    return pd.value_counts(shingleit(s, k))

f.strings.apply(count_shingles, k=3).fillna(0)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to apply your solution to the shingling example I added to my original question. Can you provide guidance? If you like, I can post it as a separate question.

Comment: @DanceParty2 I actually had this in mind when I wrote this up.  It's a very simple modification.  I've updated my post.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing, I notice with a large data frame it takes a while. I ultimately need a list of lists to pass into sci-kit learn's LSHForest like this: [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]] ...I know I can wrap np.array().tolist() around it but is there a way to by-pass putting it into a data frame (if that will save time)?

Comment: I struggled with that as well.  The only way I can improve it (that I can think of) is to use cython.  But I wouldn't expect dramatic improvements.  I'll update the post.

Comment: @DanceParty2 Yeah, not even worth posting.  I'm still figuring out how to use cython, so it could be user error.  Sorry.  If I think of anything, I'll let you know.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for trying!

Comment: By the way, a colleague suggested Scipy's sparse arrays, which I'm looking into and will update if I find what I need.